# Moment/Angular material: angular/material-moment-adapter dependency issue

Tags: angular, material-ui, angular-material, momentjs

I am trying to use @angular/material-moment-adapter in my application for a Material Datepicker and am having dependency issues. Running a simple `npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter` command states that the library requires Angular 14. I am on Angular 13 and can't upgrade.

Running `npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter --legacy-peer-deps` will allow the package to install, but wont compile and show this error:
[image]

What can I do so that I can successfully install this package and run my application?

in my package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
        "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/elements": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
        "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/google-maps": "^13.3.9",
        "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.1.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
        "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^8.1.0",
        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
        "@material/dialog": "^1.1.1",
        "@sentry/angular": "^7.7.0",
        "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
        "material-tooltip": "^1.0.1",
        "moment": "^2.26.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    },
```

And in my module:

```
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import { MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
...
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS}
  ],
```

Comment: Try specifying the version when you install: `npm i @angular/material-moment-adapter@13`

Comment: I have tried a couple including 13.3.9 and see the error `No matching version found for @angular/material-moment-adapter@13.3.9.`

Comment: @LaurenAH you can directly change dependency version my hand in `package.json` then 
 commanding `npm install`